# ubuntu ruby on rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed RoR on ubuntu 10, using all kinds so method i could find on internet, either "sudo apt-get" or "sudo gem install",  by running 'gem list', i can see they are all the latest version:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
fastthread (1.0.7)
mysql (2.8.1)
passenger (2.2.15)
rack (1.1.0)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (0.8.7)
rubygems-update (1.3.7)
```

but when i created a ror application by running 'rails samplecode', then run 'script/about', it always showed:

```
About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.8.7 (x86_64-linux)
RubyGems version          1.3.5
Rails version             2.2.3
Active Record version     2.2.3
Action Pack version       2.2.3
Active Resource version   2.2.3
Action Mailer version     2.2.3
Active Support version    2.2.3
Edge Rails revision       unknown
Application root          /home/kc/Projects/samplecode
Environment               development
Database adapter          mysql
```

why these 2 settings are different? how can i force the application to use the local gems (latest version)? Thanks.

Comment: Try running `which gem`, `which rails` and `which ruby`. See what you get on the screen and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu (aptitude/apt-get) installs gems in /var/lib/gems/1.8. When you run gem install manually, you're likely installing them in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8.

Run "gem env" and look at what the gem path(s) is/are.

If you set the GEM_HOME environment variable (GEM_HOME=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8), you can have you application look there.

Alternately, you can install the gems you want (including rails) in your application's vendor directory by putting config.gem lines in environment.rb and running rake gems:unpack:dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the `apt-get` version of Rails:

```
sudo apt-get remove rails
```

And then install Rails again using `gem`:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: I think it should be `sudo apt-get remove rails`, not `sudo apt-get uninstall rails.`